# Problems with Wordpress’ mod_rewrite rules when requesting existing files

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please take a look at my .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

For Wordpress it works fine.

But I have a problem: I have a directory called *lo*, used for links exchange, has nothing to do with the Wordpress blog.
Now, I can't access my *lo* directory, it redirects me to a wordpress post.
Why?

Comment: How do you try to access that directory?

Comment: http://www.mysite.com/lo

Comment: I have wordpress hive installed, if this helps

Comment: And the `lo` directory is inside the web root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `/lo/`'s `DirectoryIndex` point to `/lo/index.php`?

If so, and assuming your answer to Pekka's question is "Yes", the problem likely originates from the fourth `RewriteRule`. A request to `/lo/` maps to `/lo/index.php`, which matches

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```

...and gets rewritten to `index.php` in your site root, which is the WordPress file. I'm not sure what the point of this rule is (it does block access to WordPress `.php` files, but in kind of a super-general way), so I don't know what the best recommendation is for conditioning it, but the following would work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lo
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
```