# Wordpress Homepage Gets Redirected to Other CMS Home Page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed WP multisite in my root directory. I also currently have a site running in this directory using Invision Power's IP Content, but renamed the index.php file to accommodate wordpress. I am running IP Board in /forum.

I have created a wordpress page (domain.tld/sample-page/), but when navigating to it, its unable to find it (landing page is not WP, but IP Content with "we could not find the page you were looking for). It looks like my site is looking at the IP Content database before WP so it is unable to find the page/directory in its own database because /sample-page/ does not exist in it, only in the WP database.

When I go to domain.com/index.php (which should bring up my WP blog) I get redirected to my home IP Content page at www.domain.com.

How can I have it look at the WP database for things like this?

My .htaccess file:

```
# Loads home.php first (ip.content). Wordpress is index.php

DirectoryIndex home.php index.php index.html maintenance.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !.*\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home.php [L]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Multisite

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Multisite

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first set of conditions cause anything that isn't an image, file or directory to go to the home.php front controller, this prevents them from being satisfied by the similar WordPress rules.  You could add some more specific conditions to only pass certain pages to home.php or just remove that set of conditions and rules.

These two CMSs will not run well together, I'd put them on separate domains or subdomains.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I need the first set of conditions for IP Content. I tried researching what kind of conditions to add but didn't come up with much. I did find this thread, which sounds similar to my situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434610/problems-with-wordpress-mod-rewrite-rules-when-requesting-existing-files?rq=1 Do you have any ideas what kind of conditions I need?

Comment: If you have particular pages that you want WordPress to serve you could name them in the conditions that the first rewrite rule should not apply to. The apache rewrite documentation is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I tried `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(tools|learn|_)($|/.*$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1` but it still looks at IP Content and then can't find the page. If I am reading my code correctly it's saying if the URL is not domain.com/tools or learn or _ then look at index.php?

Comment: you don't need an additional RewriteRule, just some more RewriteCond statements that should look something like RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/tools$ before the rule that goes to index.php.  That would say any uri that ends in /tools doesn't go to index.php.  I have no way to test this easily, but there is a regex online tester.